# networking between two internal server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, networking

I am facing a problem that I have an static IP without domain name. I have two servers running having Local IP as 192.168.1.101, 192.168.1.102. there is a link on the index page in 1st server which redirects to 2nd server. when i hit locally it works fine. but when i try to hit from outside i.e. through INTERNET it lands on the 1st server then converts the main static IP to 192.168.1.102 in the browser i don't want to use another port for it and also don't want to use any domain name now... please help me out...

Answer (score 1):

You can't accomplish your goals with your current setup.

Presumably some device is doing the NAT-RDR / Port Forwarding to required to redirect traffic from your external IP address through your NAT device to your server at 192.168.1.101. Your RFC1918 network doesn't know anything about the Internet and conversely the Internet doesn't know anything about your RFC1918 network. Consequently, your link on 192.168.1.101 doesn't have a route to find your other server at 192.168.1.102 once you are outside your network. When you connect to 192.168.1.101 from the outside you're really just connecting with your external IP address and your NAT device does the magic to translate that through to 192.168.1.101 so when you click on the link to 192.168.1.102 your client has no idea where that machine is or how to get there.

You will need to either use a separate external address and separate NAT-RDR rule for your server at 192.168.1.102 or use a separate port on the same NAT-RDR and then update your link on 192.168.1.101 appropriately.

Comment: so, Basically you want to say that it is impossible to do so... can you tell me about NAT-RDR what does it do and other explanation...?

Comment: Sorry about that. [NAT-RDR](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/rdr.html) is a [PF](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/index.html)-ism and is just another term for Port Forwarding or PNAT.

Comment: but you know if i do some PF it will be a security risk as i have some LOGIN functionality on 101 machine and if anyone get to know about another port in same ip that is what i don't want... please help me out if you can....

Comment: What you want to do is not technically possible.